# How to access nested shadow DOM element using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, shadow-dom

So there is one download button which I want to click thru `selenium` Python but it's there inside multiple nested `shadow-dom`.

Adding screenshot for that html `dom` here

[HTML DOM Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLdT1.png)

I want to click that download button which got button as 'aria-label="Download"'

```
downloadBtn = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("body > tii-ai-writing-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("tii-router").shadowRoot.querySelector("aiwa-home").shadowRoot.querySelector("tii-sws-submission-workspace > tii-sws-header > tii-sws-download-btn-mfe").shadowRoot.querySelector("#download-popover > tii-sws-header-btn").shadowRoot.querySelector("tdl-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("button")')

driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();',downloadBtn)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on a button with a particular attribute you can use this

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Download']").click()
```

Let me know if it help